# Git called by AWX ignores manually installed root CA

Tags: ssl-certificate, centos7, git, ansible

[AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx) is installed on CentOS machine. A separate machine (`gitlab.techraf`) serves GitLab's web interface over HTTPS with a certificate signed by a private CA.

The storyline:

1. On a "fresh" system I issue the command:

   ```
   /usr/bin/git clone --origin origin https://gitlab.techraf/techraf/project.git /tmp/project
   ```

   and get (expected):

   > fatal: unable to access '`https://gitlab.techraf/techraf/project.git/`': Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
2. I install the root CA certificate on the AWX machine:

   ```
   update-ca-trust force-enable
   curl https://certificate.source/certificates/techrafCA.pem > /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/techrafCA.pem
   update-ca-trust extract
   ```
3. I retry the above `git clone`, this time getting a correct response:

   > Cloning into '/tmp/project'...
   >   remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
   >   remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
   >   Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.

   <sup>As a sanity check I ran `git clone` using different user accounts  - no problem after root CA certificate installation in point 2 - the root CA seems to be installed system-wise. `curl` also accepts the `gitlab.techraf`'s certificate.</sup>
4. **(problem)** I define a project in AWX interface and try to synchronise it from the GitLab, however I get:

   > TASK [update project using git]
   >   ************************************************
   >   fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "`/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin https://gitlab.techraf/techraf/project.git /var/lib/awx/projects/_6__project`", "failed": true, "msg": "fatal: unable to access '`https://gitlab.techraf/techraf/project.git/`': Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.", "rc": 128, "stderr": "fatal: unable to access '`https://gitlab.techraf/techraf/project.git/`': Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.\n", "stderr_lines": ["fatal: unable to access '`https://gitlab.techraf/techraf/project.git/`': Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized."], "stdout": "Cloning into '/var/lib/awx/projects/_6__project'...\n", "stdout_lines": ["Cloning into '/var/lib/awx/projects/_6__project'..."]}

   <sup>As a sanity check I tried with a project from GitHub and AWX fetches it correctly.</sup>

   <sup>As another sanity check I ran `ansible localhost -m command -a "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin https://gitlab.techraf/techraf/project.git /tmp/project2`, as well as from a different machine to ensure non-interactive shell sessions work the same. In either case the certificate was accepted.</sup>

---

What can be the cause of `git` (called by AWX/Ansible) not using the installed `techrafCA.pem` certificate?

What is the next step I can take to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: The cause is: the syncing process runs in `aws-task` container and it does not use certificates from host. The question remains, how to configure it to use those certificates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do same inside awx_task container then it works!

Verified with my AWX setup.

```
update-ca-trust force-enable
curl https://certificate.source/certificates/techrafCA.pem > /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/techrafCA.pem
update-ca-trust extract
```

Comment: if your service doesn't happen to make the pem available for you just sitting there, you can try:
```echo quit | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername "${API_HOST}" -connect "${API_HOST}":443 > cacert.pem```

Answer (score 1):

You need two files:

1. gitconfig

```
    [http]
        sslCAInfo = /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/yourca.pem
```

2. yourca.pem

Add to docker-compose.yml in task:

```
  - "./gitconfig:/etc/gitconfig"
  - "./yourca.pem:/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/yourca.pem"
```

Recreate task container `docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable GIT certificate verification completely within AWX. Add `AWX_TASK_ENV['GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY'] = 'True'` to the awx_task container and restart it:

```
docker exec -ti awx_task vi /etc/tower/settings.py
docker restart awx_task
```

Comment: That is truly a terrible idea.

Comment: This is what Red Hat recommends...
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3131461

Comment: Yes, Red Hat tends to like recommending terrible ideas.  Like paying RedHat for their recommendations.